# Check if member is in private voice channel or check if bot doesn’t have perms to join private voice channel and send error discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im making a music bot and i need to make an error that check if the member is in a private voice channel or if the bot doesn’t have perms for joining the private channel

I have tried this code:

```
interaction.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageMessages)
```

But i don’t what permission i need for the bot to join the private voice channel so i don't know what to change the ManageMessages perm to

I have check the docs, stack even youtube cant find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `joinable` property

```js
if (!interaction.member?.voice.channel?.joinable) {
    // Cant join voice channel
}
```

Or if you need to check the permissions you can use the `permissionsFor` method

```js
if (!interaction.member?.voice.channel?.permissionsFor(inteaction.guild.members.me).has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Connect)) {
    // Dont have the permissions to connect to voice channel
}
```

Note: the `?` symbols are important because the `interaction.member` and `member.voice.channel` objects are nullable. If either are, the statement is equivalent to `!null`, or `true`. This makes sense *because* there is no member/channel, so there is no channel to join in the first place.

Comment: Yup the joinable method work thank you